# Marketo - Manage Channels for Programs

Tags: marketo

I assume the values in the Channels of a Program represent the Status of the Member in the Program

If my assumption is valid,

Can i change the Channel Name or create a new Channel and associate it to a program? I would like to Rename the Channel as "Member Status"
I need to use this list for example, i have values as Added, Sent, Responded, Visited, No Interested etc...
These represent the status of the member in the program.

Is there any way to change the channel name?- This i want to do using API or Marketo setup
Is there any way to create new channel with new values? - This i want to do using API or Marketo setup
Is there any way to use this new channel with Programs? - This i want to do using API

I appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to update Channel via the API. You can read Channels, but not update. Channel is not commonly changed, it's usually a one-time setup, therefore there is no API at this time.

This is the documentation on reading Channels: http://developers.marketo.com/rest-api/endpoint-reference/asset-endpoint-reference/#!/Channels/getAllChannelsUsingGET

Comment: Ok, thanks i got that...but your earlier answer was a life saver :)

Comment: Is there any option in REST or SOAP to add new Campaign, instead of Program?

Comment: i am using GetLeadsByProgramID to get the Leads with Status under a Program. But is there any way where i can get status of only 1 lead for a program?